# Bootstrap modal shows for a second then dissapears

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

So basically i am creating an inbox where data are loaded from my db. but i am having trouble triggering my modal, i have searched but nothing matches my problem. The button to trigger was inside a `<form method="post">` because i have a hidden `input` to check for the id of the row that as been clicked.
Btw, my button that will trigger the modal will also execute two (2) mysqli queries.
Here's my code:

```
<form method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="key" value="'.$value->id.'">
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" title="View" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" name="inbox_view">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span></button>
<button title="Trash" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" name="inbox_del">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
</form>
```

The code for executing my queries:

```
if(isset($_POST['inbox_view'])){
    $id = filter($_POST['key']);
    $type = '1';
    $stmt = $dbcon->query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE id='$id' AND type='1'") or die(mysqli_error());
    $stmt2 = $dbcon->prepare("UPDATE messages SET seen='0' WHERE id=?") or die(mysqli_error());
    $stmt2->bind_param('s',$id);
    $stmt2->execute();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt)){
    $sender=$row['sender'];
    $msg=$row['msg'];
    $mdate=$row['mdate'];
    }
}
```

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade-in" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><?php echo $value->sender; ?></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- Description-->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
          <p class="wrap"><?php echo $value->msg?></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Description-->
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      Received: <?php echo $value->mdate ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What am i doing wrong? and what do i need to make this work?
PS: The update query is to check whether the mail is read
Unread Messages = bold
Read Messages = normal

Comment: Bootstrap does not care about your backend. Providing the JS would me more appropriate. My guess would be that you accidentally close the modal after retrieving a XHR response or you don't use XHR at all and the modal will not be closed but you browser is sending an ordinary POST request which is why the page reloads.

Comment: I'm not familiar with bootstrap. But I'm missing something. Where are you sending the form? I would expect either an input submit or a javascript function that listens to the button click or something and then fires the post

Comment: @Gerard what do you mean "Where am i sending the form?" i'm using `<form method="post">` to get the value of `<input type="hidden">` and then uses it for my select query.

Comment: @NilsRückmann Sorry but as much as possible i wont use JS because i'm not yet familiar with it.

Comment: @ronstoppable I mean that there should be an action that triggers the form to make the post. This can either be an <input type="submit"> or a javascript function. Or maybe is something that bootstrap does somehow

Comment: @Gerard oh i forgot, it is a `<button type="submit">`. This button does the following: 1. triggers modal 2. execute select query 3. execute update query

Comment: yes that makes sense. I think @NilsRückmann is right

Answer (score 1):

Your browser is submitting the form on click of the button. This is why it seems like the modal is closed. In fact you are seeing a new (but the same) page after the form is send. You will need to create a XHR Request to submit data without navigating.

See https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ for more details.

Comment: I'm not familiar with AJAX tbh, but can you provide me an instruction on how actually would i do this?

Comment: AJAX only means that the request is done asynchronous (in relation to your document request). In simple term: Do request X, but keep the current page. I think the example on jquery.com should provide everything you need: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/#example-7

Comment: I don't really get how will i do it with AJAX, but thanks for sparing your time answering my question, i'm trying to analyze what the example is really trying to do.